# SQL Query to re-align column order

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

This is my `Select` query.

```
select * 
from  
    #temptableforRiskDisiplineStaLvl 
inner join 
    #temptableforRiskDisipline on #temptableforRiskDisiplineStaLvl.PROJ_ID = #temptableforRiskDisipline.PROJ_ID
```

Which is fetching below result set.

```
PROJ_ID test Risk_Status    test2 Risk_Status   PROJ_ID     test Owner      test2 Owner
  20            Green           Red                 20              XXXXXX          NULL
  21            NULL            NULL                21          YYYYYY          NULL
```

Is there any way to re-align my column order into this format?

```
PROJ_ID test Risk_Status    test Owner  test2 Risk_Status   test2 Owner.
```

The main thing here is two temp tables columns are dynamically generated from other table columns using PIVOT. So I could not judge what are all the table columns going to be.

Comment: and ? what is the use ? why you want to realign?

Comment: This is user requirement. But anyhow, i have same question in my mind. They want  column to be each Risk Status & it's owner ...

Comment: Guys, who are down voting please understand the question and downvote it..If you dont understand question properly, ask for justification..

Comment: this should be modified with whatever language used to read the results of the query, sort the array

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a lot of details about your current table structure and which columns come from each table but it appears that you should be able to just re-order the columns - no PIVOT would be needed:

```
select l.Proj_id,
  l.[test Risk_Status],
  d.[test Owner],
  l.[test2 Risk_Status],
  d.[test2 Owner]
from #temptableforRiskDisiplineStaLvl l
inner join #temptableforRiskDisipline d
  on l.PROJ_ID = d.PROJ_ID
```

Comment: Thanks..I have a pivot query which will fetch dynamic result based on the values present in XXX & YYY (Basically XXX  & YYY tables values converted as column.) So i am not sure what how many columns going to be in the result set. I am trying to re-align these table columns. This is what my requirement is. I understand above query will fetch correct result. But what will happen in case XXX & YYY table values are changed.

Comment: I managed to write algorithm in .NET to re-align these dataset columns.